Looking for a book about appropriate punishment for "barbaric" worlds
I am looking for the name of a novella I read but forgot it. I read it online around 20 years ago.
It is set in a distant future with a multi-species galactic community. The story is told from the point of view of a "barbaric" visitor of one of the advanced worlds. It skips some compulsory information for every visitor, then does many things and ends up in jail. In jail, he robed jacket from another prisoner.
In jail, approached by officials and told that the civilised worlds decided to revise their policy regarding the "barbaric" world to react appropriately: "civilised" punishments for citizens of "civilised" worlds, and "barbaric" punishment for citizens of "barbaric" worlds. The official is asking the main character if he would cooperate and provide more information about the legal system of his "barbaric" world so they can punish them according to their laws. As alternative local official propose to remove prisoner's arm, because according to prisoner's laws, he attacked "free person" and steal from "free person".
